# "Of his" or "of him" in this situation?

Tags: prepositions, double-possessive

The sentence I saw on a TV series:

> I wanna grab him by that stupid knit tie of his.

First I saw it, I thought it is incorrect because I only saw the use of "of him" before. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: What research have you done concerning possessive pronouns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. It is a case of ***oblique genitive***. You will find plenty of sites calling it ***double genitive*** or ***double possessive***, like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Syntax):

> The genitive can be combined with an ***of*** *construction* to produce what is often called a *double genitive*, as in the following examples:
>
> - that hard heart *of **thine*** (*Venus and Adonis*, line 500)
> - this extreme exactness *of **his*** (Sterne, *Tristram Shandy*, chapter 1.IV)

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20genitive#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20double%20genitive,%E2%80%94%20called%20also%20double%20possessive) defines the double genitive as:

> a syntactic construction in English in which possession is *marked both by the preposition **of** and a noun or **pronoun in the possessive case***
>
> - A friend o***f Bob's*** is a friend ***of mine***.

However, Wikipedia notes that:

> Some object to the name double genitive because *the "of" clause is not a genitive*. Alternative names are "**oblique genitive**".

Indeed, on page 469, CAGEL has a note that says:

> The oblique genitive construction is commonly referred to as the 'double genitive'. [...] However, we do not regard ***of*** as a genitive case marker, and hence there is only one genitive here, not two.

Note that this structure, *that + noun + of + possessive*, can sometimes express disapproval or irritation (like in your example) but also affection or admiration, depending on context.

Consider

> Oh, those green eyes of hers!

and

> When are you going to show me that amazing invention of yours?

Comment: Neat. Without this usage it would be hard to convey concisely and precisely the meaning of the last example.

Comment: Thank you so much.